# Get class attribute using SimpleHTMLDOM

Tags: php, simple-html-dom, web-crawler

I am trying to get the value of the attribute `class` using the following code

```
foreach($sub->children() as $child){
    if($child->class!=="viewAll"){
        echo $child->plaintext."<br>";
    }
}
```

I am unable get the class value. How can I achieve this?

**update**
I am traversing through this source. Am I wrong in logic?

[image]

Comment: @sanki i need to get using SimpleHtmlDom because this an automatic server side scripting.

Comment: Have you tried the manual? http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: yes they mentioned as i did in above question but not working for me

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: i m getting no error but the condition is not working

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I assume you are looking for `<li>` elements without the class `viewAll`.

You may need to check whether the class attribute exists first. Try this:

```
foreach($sub->children() as $child){
    # child element doesn't have a class attrib
    if (! $child->hasAttribute('class') || 
    # or child element has a class but it is not 'viewAll'
       ($child->hasAttribute('class') && $child->getAttribute('class') !== 'viewAll'))
        echo $child->plaintext."<br>";
    }
}
```

Or, in the simple-html-dom style, this:

```
$lis = $html->find('ul li[!class]');
foreach ($lis as $li) {
    echo $li->plaintext."<br>";
}
```